# Typeface Override have no effect on LayoutInflater

Tags: android, textview, layout-inflater, truetype

to Override Font AllOver The Application I Use This

```
 public class TypefaceOverride {

  public static void override(Context context, String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
  }

  private static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName, final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
      final Field staticField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
      staticField.setAccessible(true);
      staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And then this method on application class

```
private void typeFace() {
    TypefaceOverride.override(this, "DEFAULT", "iran_sans.ttf");
    TypefaceOverride.override(this, "MONOSPACE", "iran_sans.ttf");
    TypefaceOverride.override(this, "SERIF", "iran_sans.ttf");
    TypefaceOverride.override(this, "SANS_SERIF", "iran_sans.ttf");
  }
```

all fonts change as well , but when i

```
 LinearLayout product = (LinearLayout) G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.product, null);
 TextView txt = (TextView) product.findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

TextView Font Dont get Effect And I Have To set font on it

```
  txt.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(G.context, "iran_sans.ttf"));
```

And Also there is RecycleView in LinearLayout That Inflated but **colorEdgeEffect** have wrong color (gray !)

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn Education ! , Why My English Is So Bad
Finally found The Solution

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Just Need To Add Context

```
   LinearLayout product = (LinearLayout) G.inflater.cloneInContext(ActivityMain.this).inflate(R.layout.product, null);
```